# Select option not visible on blade syntax (laravel 5.5)

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.5

I am new in laravel 5.5, I got a problem where my **select** on **Blade syntax** not visible (hidden).

Here is my blade code :

```
{{ Form::select('id_jurusan',[
    '1' => 'Teknik Informatika',
    '2' => 'Teknik Sipil'],1,['id' => 'jurusan']
) }}
```

[when I inspect the html is show the code but in hidden condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOW12.png)

The question why this not visible?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

In controller:

```
$data['data']=['1' => 'Teknik Informatika',
               '2' => 'Teknik Sipil'];
return view('folder.blade_template',$data);
```

In View:

```
{{ Form::select('id_jurusan',['Select Option']+$data ,1,['id' => 'jurusan'] ) }}
```

Comment: thank for answering , it work but it still hidden,,,

Comment: i'm sorry I did not understand ??
I try the code in your answer it work ,,,I can se the select option using f12 (html inspect) but in the browser id does not show any select :(
I just change create function on controller and view when I use your code...

Comment: @DekiAkbar I mean when you create select option by default hide class will apply on it. So please check it's class.

Comment: where is the class position?? in .blade.php?? or in controller?? sorry im new in laravel

Answer (score 0):

Try with this -

```
$data = ['Teknik Informatika','Teknik Sipil'];

{!!Form::select('id_jurusan', $data, 1, ['id' => 'jurusan'])!!}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: what error you are getting?cause syntax of  form select  is -
 {!!Form::select('name', [options-values], option-id, ['id' => 'selectId'])!!}

Comment: i put this in controller $data = ['Teknik Informatika','Teknik Sipil'];
and this on blade template {!!Form::select('id_jurusan', $data, 1, ['id' => 'jurusan'])!!}

its say unknown variable data, here is the error :

Undefined variable: data (View: /home/deki/www/siakad/resources/views/Mahasiswa/mahasiswaInsert.blade.php)

Comment: In controller, $response['data']=[ 'Teknik Informatika', 'Teknik Sipil'];
return view('folder.blade_template',$response);  pass data like this and then pass it in form selection {!!Form::select('id_jurusan', $data, 1, ['id' => 'jurusan'])!!}

Comment: i works but stil hidden ...the option is work fine but thee select still hiden and not visible...